# Can you make the bubble size and color dependend on a MDX measure in icCube amChart widget?

Tags: amcharts, iccube, iccube-reporting

I am trying to make a dynamic chart in icCube, in which bubbles are sized and colored in accordance with a specific data field in the MDX result set.

Example MDX result set:
(the x/y coordinates have been removed for the sake of simplicity):

```
        amount  color     bullet size
Swiss    100    #0000FF       10
Spain    120    #FF0000       12
NL       70     #00FF00        7
```

I do not know how to do this now in the amChart widget in icCube, but I know it is possible to do this in amCharts itself. You can set for example the following attributes in the amCharts editor:

- Alpha field, Bullet field, Bullet size field, Description field, Fill colors field, Label color field, Line color field, ... etc (see for more in the amCharts live editor).

Enclosed a sample chart with two series, in which one has colored bubbles:
[example](http://live.amcharts.com/M3MGI/)

Is it possible in icCube web reporting to do this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible:

The table should look like this:

[image: example data]

In your amCharts bubble widget, add the following in Graph:

```
"colorField":"color" //the name of the column that contains the colors
```

and set use mdx colors to "no".

[image: color field]

I named my colorField "kleur". Any value here is possible, but it has to be the same as the column name that contains the colors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, just you have to write the following into the "Extra Options" field:

```
:{
    graphs:[{
        xField: "your_x_field",
        yField: "your_y_field",
        valueField: "amount",
        bulletSizeField: "bullet size",
        bullet : "round",
        colorField: "color"
    }]
}
```

Note that, your graphs defined above will be overwritten by this one, you have to specify here all the graph settings.

Comment: Thanks both István and Tom.