# using icCube HSL color formula to set the color for the amChart values

Tags: amcharts, iccube-reporting

Following the answers on [my previous question in June](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725575/can-you-make-the-bubble-size-and-color-dependend-on-a-mdx-measure-in-iccube-amch), I would like to use the icCube [HSL() formula](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/HSL.php) to define the colors of the chart members in the amChart widget.

In the standard schema Sales I use the following MDX:

```
with
member [measures].[hue] as 16
member [measures].[saturation] as 1-indexof([Rubriek].[Rubriek].currentmember.siblings,[Rubriek].[Rubriek].currentmember)/30
member [measures].[lightness] as 0.2+ordinal(level([Rubriek].[Rubriek].currentmember))/10
member [measures].[color-hsl] as hsl([hue],[saturation],[lightness])
member [measures].[color-fixed] as "#FF0000"

SELECT
{ {[Measures].[Amount],[measures].[color-hsl],[measures].[color-fixed]} } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Product].[Product].firstNotAllLevel().allmembers } ON ROWS
 FROM [Sales]
```

I have added 2 color fields:

- color-hsl = the HSL defined color based on level depth of the product hierarchy and the position of the member among its siblings
- color-fixed = just a hexadecimal color, for testing purposes

Now when I define a combo chart, I can set the color field in the 'Advanced properties':

- [{"colorField":"color-hsl"}]

Except, this does not give me the calculated colors. But, if I change the colorField to color-fixed it gives me the red color as defined.

**Questions:**

1. How can I achieve that the color-hsl is working. Do I have to convert it to a hexadeximal string? How can I achieve that?
2. How can I get rid of the data value for color-hsl. I only want to use this as a field to define the color, not the value (that is the "Amount") field in my mdx?

Comment: 1. answered, 2. it's not clear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color function in MDX returns an integer value, e.g. 2334. If you want to use it in a browser you've to convert it to the hexadecimal string representation :

[ToHexColor](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Java%20Functions.php)( colorAsInteger )  that returns